# Template manipulation in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to modify an Angular template before any other directive is triggered, in particular interpolation. I am doing this through the `compile` option in the directive definition.

Here is my test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
      angular.module('soQuestion', [])
        .directive('example', function () {
          return {

            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
              if (tAttrs.foo && tAttrs.foo.match(/^keyword/)) {
                tElement.attr('foo', 'prefix-' + tAttrs.foo);
                console.log(tElement.attr('foo'));
              }
            }

          };
        })
        .controller('controller', function($scope) {
          $scope.value = 'something';
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="soQuestion">
    <div ng-controller="controller">
        <div example foo="keyword_{{value}}"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

However, the final result that I get is `<div foo="keyword_something"></div>` instead of `<div foo="prefix-keyword_something"></div>`, even if the `compile` function was triggered properly. What is going on here?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/KLbmu/ did it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('soQuestion', [])
    .directive('example', function () {
      return {

        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
          if (tAttrs.foo && tAttrs.foo.match(/^keyword/)) {
            // Change the tAttrs hash instead of the element itself
            tAttrs.foo = 'prefix-' + tAttrs.foo;
            // Change the element too, in case no interpolation is present
            tElement.attr('foo', tAttrs.foo);
            console.log(tElement.attr('foo'));
          }
        }

      };
    })
```

Explanation: the `interpolate` directive does check for changes in the attribute value. However it doesn't look again on the DOM node itself but on the `tAttrs` hash.

---

**Old pessimistic answer:**

I don't think it's possible to achieve the desired result.

Looking at Angular's source, [`collectDirectives`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/451bde124497a4fdae19a4f7e89c42cd3715ac09/src/ng/compile.js#L976) puts together the list of directives that affect a certain node. Their respective `compile` functions are collected and then sorted by priority. The problem is that the compile function of `{{}}` is then bound to `keyword_{{value}}` and is not affected by the `example` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Its a directive priority issue, and admittedly I still don't completely understand. But don't for get that `{{}}` is itself a directive. Its getting applied in some order with yours, and overwriting your manipulation. If its terminal and high priority, it clears up.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/PGAs4/)

```
angular.module('soQuestion', [])
.directive('example', function () {
    return {
        priority: 1000,
        terminal : true,
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (tAttrs.foo && tAttrs.foo.match(/^keyword/)) {
                tElement.attr('foo', 'prefix-' + tAttrs.foo);
                console.log(tElement.attr('foo'), tElement[0]);
            }
            return function(){};
        }

    };
})
.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'something';
});
```

because this breaks the `{{}}` I would consider compiling the attr manually as well.